# Associating automated tests in Azure with XUnit shows "None" as outcome

Tags: azure, automation, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, xunit

I am trying to associate my automation with their test cases in Azure, but I keep running into an issue where after it runs, the outcome is "None" and the TC shows as In Progress. I have followed these two resources to a T:

[Resource 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops)

[Resource 2](https://www.marcusfelling.com/blog/2020/associating-automated-tests-with-azure-test-cases/)

with the same result on both. Is there something obvious that I'm missing when setting this up?

Here is the result: [test run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq6LA.png)

Here are my settings for the pipeline and test plan:[Test Plan Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVnw7.png) [Installer Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZwVG.png) [VS Test Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moUja.png)

Answer (score 0):

Rather try to run the vstest task using "Select tests using=Test plan". More https://stackoverflow.com/a/71921582/2252417

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).