# Azure DevOps - Can't link automated tests for Azure DevOps, outcome always shows: "In progress" instead "Failed" or "Passed"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm new on DevOps Azure. I'm trying to link my automated tests for Azure DevOps platform, but outcome is always "In progress". I don't get failed or passed for any test. I created my tests in Visual Studio C#.
I created app and CheckIn it in Visual Studio and it's showed in Repos File, also my test folder is shown too. If I do changes in my code it's updated in Repos. So it is fine.

[image: Clipboard-File-1.png](/attachment/file/6a37d240-f794-48ae-a265-0bab228f4b95)]

Then, I created Pipeline:TestMirjana-.NET Desktop-CI
[image: Clipboard-File-2.png](/attachment/file/36749947-2c2d-461e-b74b-f145ff3e39f9)]

and build is successful for this one. Than, I created Release linked for this pipeline:
[image: Clipboard-File-3.png](/attachment/file/675ed7e0-fd0e-4b4f-8080-991d4fef7cdc)]

and it is successful too.

I linked my test case for Visual Studio:
[image: Clipboard-File-5.png](/attachment/file/45df4b6c-1c68-4ab0-ae39-8f6430cbc9e4)]

also linked Test Plan Settings for these pipeline and release

[image: Clipboard-File-6.png](/attachment/file/8dcc18c2-c545-4d6a-9c80-4ddc3ca559a7)]

but when I run my test case Outcome is always "In progress", no other results shown (not failed or passed)
[image: Clipboard-File-7.png](/attachment/file/3047ee58-e5d9-4336-b28c-b149495a1f61)]

validation is good
[image: Clipboard-File-8.png](/attachment/file/e783523a-70ba-4226-b540-253c1171721f)]

but Outcome is always None
[image: Clipboard-File-9.png](/attachment/file/e9d7bd68-534a-4ff7-aab1-8499a649dd88)].

So, I'm not sure why it's not working properly.
Maybe I didn't link something properly, can you please support?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The 'In Progress' result means it has some automation associated but there are no incoming results (having the required test configuration).

Try to run the vstest task in the Release pipeline (instead of the build pipeline) and use "Select tests using=Test plan" and pick the Test plan where you expect to see the results from automated tests. It works for me.